# Response code 404 in python requests, opens normally in the browser

Tags: python, python-requests, httprequest

I'm trying to requests.get this page in python requests but get error code 404. It opens normally in the browser. What's wrong here?

```
requests.get('https://www.shararam.ru/su/Build/2022.09.20.json')
<Response [404]>
```

Comment: The hosting site is likely discouraging automated access and returning a "Not Found" error if the request doesn't look like it came from a browser.

Comment: Any way to go around this? I tried changing the headers but it didn't help.

Comment: I won't help you circumvent the policies of a public site. Perhaps you can contact the owner of the domain.

Comment: Okay if so, but I really don't have any malicious intent here. I'd be very grateful if someone explained this one to me.

Comment: Set user-agent to mimic the browser request

Comment: That's what I tried already, didn't work.

Comment: Seems like the server doesn't trust your request.  Might need to add header to seem "normal"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always figure out the correct headers that are needed from the server to accept your request. In my case i tried with:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
```

And worked. It seems that accept encoding was the key in this case.

Answer (score 2):

try with requests session:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.shararam.ru/su/Build/2022.09.20.json"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'}
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(url, timeout=30, headers=headers)     

print(r.status_code) 
200

print(r.json())

{'companyName': 'NewMedia',
 'productName': 'Shararam',
 'productVersion': '0.2',
 'dataUrl': '2022.09.20.data.unityweb',
 'wasmCodeUrl': '2022.09.20.wasm.code.unityweb',
 'wasmFrameworkUrl': '2022.09.20.wasm.framework.unityweb',
 'graphicsAPI': ['WebGL 2.0', 'WebGL 1.0'],
 'webglContextAttributes': {'preserveDrawingBuffer': False},
 'splashScreenStyle': 'Dark',
 'backgroundColor': '#231F20',
 'developmentBuild': False,
 'multithreading': False,
 'unityVersion': '2019.4.21f1'}
```

Comment: Does this work for you? I'm still getting 404 on my machine.

Comment: yes, the output is from the executed code in mt computer, what you get when you visit this url in your browser (chrome/firefox)?

Comment: The same as your answer, I only get 404 in python. What do you get after doing this? requests.get('https://www.shararam.ru/su/Build/2022.09.20.json')

Comment: <Response [200]>